# How to embedded swagger folder into web api application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

[image]

Hi all ,

we are currently using swagger in our web api application , when ever i want call swagger ui it was redirected to http://localhost:5080/Swagger/index.html  and it working fine ,because the folder which swagger reside im having full access to that folder , now while we are moved into production environment we dont have access that folder , i want to embedded my swagger in to my application  is there any nice idea to embedded into my web api application ?

TIA
Samba

Comment: How about placing the swagger source files into the webapp directory of your application and hence deploy it together with the app?

Comment: Now im implementing to convert into application  resource and trying to redirect that homepage ,still im trying to implement